mostrar más de un registro de un geojson en un popup en leaflet
Se tiene un mapa en Leaflet con datos que están en un geojson. Este geojson tiene polígonos y algunos de ellos tienen puntos en común. Al hacer click  en un punto para que me muestre información de ese punto, solo me muestra la información del punto asociado a un polígono, aunque el punto pertenezca a dos polígonos del geojson. Es decir, en cada popup que se muestra al clickear el ratón, solo muestra el popoup y la información con un registro.
Como podría mostrar un popup con todos los registros asociados al punto dónde he clickeado?
Este es el código en leaflet de la función onEachFeature de la capa geojson:
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                                    var popupContent = "<br>INFORMACIÓN " + "</br>";
                                    var props = feature.properties;
                                    var attrs = Object.keys(props);
                                    var attribute;
                                    var value;
                                    popupContent += "<table class='table'>";
                                    popupContent += "<tr>";
                                    for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i += 1) {
                                                attribute = attrs[i];
                                                value = props[attribute];
                                                popupContent += "<td>" + attribute + ": " + value + "</td>";
                                    };
                                    popupContent += "</tr>";
                                    popupContent += "</table>";
                                            
                                    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                                            
                                },

